# Is there a bug in all mysql export file with timestamp on non UTC servers?

Tags: javascript, mysql, timezone, amazon-aurora

Just had to move a sql database from one server over to the other

I understand a timestamp field in MYSQL is stored as an 4byte integer (timezone agnostic) and presented to the user in it current server (mysql server) timezone setting
Am I right?

Now When time changes from summer time to winder time in Europe (UTC+2 to UTC+1) in October, there are times overlapping for one hour.

This makes sense and is not an issue because we 'know' the server knows the difference because it stores thim in unix utc timestamp.

Am I Still right ?

Now when I moved my database export from one database to the other, the timestamp field is not moved as in integer, but as a human readable time string :

just a sample :

```
(1,'AAAA01',6.50,NULL,NULL,NULL,'2017-07-28 17:38:16',0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,NULL),
(2,'AAAA01',6.50,NULL,NULL,NULL,'2017-07-28 20:00:00',1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,NULL),
(3,'AAAA01',6.00,NULL,NULL,NULL,'2017-07-28 21:39:07',0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,NULL),
(4,'AAAA01',5.50,NULL,NULL,NULL,'2017-07-28 21:42:15',0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,NULL),
(5,'AAAA01',5.00,NULL,NULL,NULL,'2017-07-29 12:55:48',0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,NULL),
```

You can see this field :

```
`received` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

but stored as a human readable field.

How does the receiving server knows if this field is before or after time change (in October)

Timechange happens 2 times a year , In spring it goes forward one hour, so there is no confusion as there is just a one hour gap, but in autumn it goes backwards and 'overwrites' the same hour..

### Timezone conversion

How can the Mysql Server even give an answer to this time as it represents 2 different times:

SELECT CONVERT_TZ( '2018-10-28 02:40', 'Europe/Paris', 'UTC' )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time zone of a MySQL server is only the *default* time zone used for these conversions.  It can be overridden on a per-connection basis.  That is what happens, here, to make this work.

When `mysqldump` queries the server to retrieve the data to write to the backup file, it starts by sending this:

```
SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00';
```

This sets the session (connection) time zone for mysqldump's connection to be UTC, which causes those `TIMESTAMP` columns to be sent by the server in UTC and written that way to the backup file.

Near the top of the dump file, it also adds this:

```
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
```

The `/*! ... */` [is not really a comment](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comments.html), even though it looks like one.  The `!40103` signals any MySQL server version 4.01.03 or later to execute the embedded statement as normal -- thus setting the session time zone on the connection where the dump is being restored to also be UTC so that these timestamps-as-strings are stored correctly.

`DATETIME` columns do not do these conversions -- only `TIMESTAMP`... but for `TIMESTAMP` columns, there should be no incorrect values on the new server.  The values in the dump file are UTC -- which is also the native internal storage format's time zone (not technically agnostic at all).

---

Note also that it is no longer considered a best practice to set the time zone for a server to anything other than UTC.  Local times are a presentation issue, best handled by the application, not the database.  UTC has no ambiguities like local time zones can -- such as the missing hour in spring and the duplicated hour in the fall, found in many local time zones.